# Where can I find documentation for ComputerCraftEdu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft, minecraft-education-edition

> ### Summary of Answer
>
> Written documentation is available in an archived copy of the mod’s wiki. It’s currently accessible here:
> http://web.archive.org/web/20161126140402/http://services.minecraftedu.com/wiki/ComputerCraftEdu (accessed 2019-10-12)
>
> *The link above was provided by Fabian Röeling. His full answer is available herein.*

---

I'm a teacher and Minecraft noob, and I been playing around with the education edition of ComputerCraft, i.e., ComputerCraft**Edu**. It uses programmable turtles, but with a more accessible GUI. However, I cannot locate any printed documentation; the URL for the mod's wiki seems to be broken:

> Broken link: http://services.minecraftedu.com/wiki/ComputerCraftEdu

This web address is referenced on at least two authoritative sites, e.g., [computercraftedu.com](https://computercraftedu.com) and [the developer's site](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/computercraftedu).

I presume this issue may have something to do with the change of the "MinecraftEdu" product to "Minecraft: Education Edition." Presumably, this name change also affected the domain name of the related website, i.e., http://minecraftedu.com currently redirects to https://education.minecraft.net/.

That said, I tried modifying the problematic URL to point to the newer domain, but I came up short. I also tried contacting the distributor of the mod and the mod's developer, but I was unsuccessful.

**Does the wiki exist on a new site? Or is there a new path on the new site? Does written documentation exist anywhere else?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing two different games here: "ComputerCraft" is a modification for "Minecraft Java edition", while "Education edition" is a variant of (and partially included in) Minecraft Bedrock edition/Pocket edition/Windows 10 edition/… (it has many names, very confusing). MCJava and MCPE are two different games, sharing no code and nothing of either is compatible with the other (mods, resource packs, world saves, …).

I haven't heart about "ComputerCraftEdu" before, but there are only really two possibilities:

1. It's a variant of ComputerCraft for education purposes, but still for Minecraft Java edition, then its scripting is probably similar or identical to the normal ComputerCraft mod and only the GUI is different.
2. It's a complete remake of the mod for Bedrock edition (I don't know if MCPE mods even exist), then it might have similar scripting, it might not. If you can't find documentation for it, I recommend using the regular ComputerCraft for MCJava. I heard that the scripting it pretty straightforward and easy to learn.

ComputerCraftEdu is definitely not the same thing as "Minecraft Education edition", ComputerCraft is a third party modification while Education edition is an official Mojang product.

Also, whenever a website is not available or working anymore, I always recommend checking https://web.archive.org. The link you mentioned was for example saved there 69 times over the years, 37 of them appear to be working fine (I didn't try the Flash player bits), this is the latest of those: http://web.archive.org/web/20161126140402/http://services.minecraftedu.com/wiki/ComputerCraftEdu

Comment: Actually, I’m not confused, but maybe my post was. :-). Both ComputerCraft and ComputerCraftEdu are indeed mods for the Java versions of Minecraft, both the educational edition and the regular one. I’ve installed both of these mods on my regular Java version of Minecraft, and they work fine. I’m just seeking documentation for the ComputerCraftEdu mod.

Comment: Also, I already scoured archive.org. I only found the wiki’s home page, but couldn’t locate the other content.

Comment: I just tried clicking on 6 different links on that page, all of them worked fine. They opened archives of those linked pages.

Comment: That’s great news. I must have tried a different archive, though, because it didn’t work for me. Would you mind posting the link for the wiki’s top-level page that successfully led you to the other six?

Comment: I did, that is the one in the answer.